# Errors with amdgpu-dmks on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, apt, amd-graphics

I have been trying to install AMD GPU drivers (for the RX5500M) and have been facing multiple issues. Now,
whenever I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or any install with `apt-get`), I recieve the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
amdgpu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking at the crash log, the following can be seen:

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for amdgpu-5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04 for kernel 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
 Tuesday 13 December 2022 04:09:28 AM IST
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/Makefile:26: "Local GCC version 110303 does not match kernel compiler GCC version 110300"
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/Makefile:27: "This may cause unexpected and hard-to-isolate compiler-related issues"
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/drm_gem_ttm_helper.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/scheduler/sched_main.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/scheduler/sched_fence.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/scheduler/sched_entity.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_tt.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/main.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_util.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/symbols.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_vm.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_common.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kernel_params.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/dma-buf/dma-resv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_backlight.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ioctl.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kthread.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_io.o
   LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amddrm_ttm_helper.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_perf_event.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_module.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_execbuf_util.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_range_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_resource.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_seq_file.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_suspend.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mm.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_device.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_sys_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_memory.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sched.o
   LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/scheduler/amd-sched.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_kms.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence_array.o
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_device.c:28: warning: "pr_fmt" redefined
    28 | #define pr_fmt(fmt) "[TTM DEVICE] " fmt
       | 
 In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:19,
                  from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                  from ./include/linux/preempt.h:11,
                  from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:55,
                  from ./include/linux/kref.h:16,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/include/kcl/kcl_kref.h:15,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:6,
                  from <command-line>:
 ./include/linux/printk.h:340: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   340 | #define pr_fmt(fmt) fmt
       | 
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_reservation.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_agp_backend.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_atombios.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_cache.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_auth.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_fb.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_print.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fbmem.o
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/ttm_device.c:28: warning: "pr_fmt" redefined
    28 | #define pr_fmt(fmt) "[TTM DEVICE] " fmt
       | 
 In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:19,
                  from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                  from ./include/linux/preempt.h:11,
                  from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:55,
                  from ./include/linux/kref.h:16,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/include/kcl/kcl_kref.h:15,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:6,
                  from <command-line>:
 ./include/linux/printk.h:340: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   340 | #define pr_fmt(fmt) fmt
       | 
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_crtc.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_connector.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_crtc.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_atomic_helper.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_connectors.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_device_cgroup.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mn.o
   LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/ttm/amdttm.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_modes.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atom.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_time.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ftrace.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_acpi_table.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_page_alloc.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_numa.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fs_read_write.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_aperture.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_simple_kms_helper.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_bitmap.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_vmscan.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_dma_fence_chain.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mce_amd.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fence.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_hdcp.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_debugfs_inode.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sysfs_emit.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_object.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_encoders.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gart.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_display.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_i2c.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gem.o
   LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/amdkcl.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ring.o
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.c: In function ‘amdgpu_ssg_init’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.c:2313:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct percpu_ref’ from type ‘struct percpu_ref *’
  2313 |         adev->ssg.pgmap.ref = &adev->ssg.ref;
       |                               ^
 make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.o] Error 1
 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_cs.o
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:560: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:1903: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.15.0-56-generic
Date: Tue Dec 13 04:09:34 2022
DuplicateSignature: dkms:amdgpu-dkms-firmware:1:5.16.9.22.20.50200-1438747~22.04:/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.c:2313:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct percpu_ref’ from type ‘struct percpu_ref *’
Package: amdgpu-dkms-firmware 1:5.16.9.22.20.50200-1438747~22.04
PackageVersion: 1:5.16.9.22.20.50200-1438747~22.04
SourcePackage: amdgpu-dkms
Title: amdgpu-dkms-firmware 1:5.16.9.22.20.50200-1438747~22.04: amdgpu kernel module failed to build
```

I'm unable to install any packages now, what exactly is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: AMD graphics drivers are open-source, selected at the time of the Ubuntu installation (if there's compatible hardware) and just run. No user action required. What exactly have you tried to install?

Comment: I tried running amdgpu-install

Comment: That's the proprietary overlay, the same drivers you already have - again, if you have compatible hardware - plus a couple of proprietary stuff that you very likely DON'T need at all. BTW, which AMD graphics do you have? Please always [edit] the question to add information such as what just asked.

Comment: I edited it to include the GPU name.

Comment: Yes, it runs with `amdgpu` which, again, is already installed. Do you have any reason to want to install the drivers from AMD? If not then don't, it's as simple as that. Nothing else to add.

Comment: Don't I need to upgrade my GPU drivers?

Comment: Actually, a lot of programs (especially games) require the AMD Specific drivers. So, popping off (looking at you @ChanganAuto) on all of the questions seeking help on this issue is *SO NOT HELPFUL*.
Let the question be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by undoing the attempt I made at installing the driver.

Answer (score -1):

Simply removing the amdgpu-dkms package would do the same thing, yet, that's not a fix... but a band-aid to ignore the real problem.

But, here is the command line to do so:

```
sudo apt remove amdgpu-dkms
```

Sadly, as I am having this exact same issue, and I have installed / uninstalled the AMD gpu drivers a thousand times today (to the point that I have all of the options memorized), I do not have a real solution to offer other than the ignore it style answer.

If someone comes along with an actual answer - please post it so that it can be resolved. I really need to have this working too.